# How to reverse command dial for Fujifilm X100s?

Tags: camera-settings, fujifilm-x100

Coming from a Canon system where turning clockwise means increase and counter-clockwise to mean decrease in value, I'm having trouble adjusting to X100s' reversed way. I found an option to do this for the focusing ring, but don't see anything for the command dial.

Is there something that I missed in the settings? Or is it simply impossible with the shipped firmware? If that's the case, are there any workarounds (e.g. custom firmwares) for me to achieve what I need?

Comment: No idea if this is possible, not by official functions at least but I know what it's like. Last week I was reviewing the Olympus E-M1 and I kept turning the zoom the wrong direction. Nikon for a long time had the EC indicators and dials reversed, drove people with dual systems crazy!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, on the X100s or on any newer Fujifilm X camera I'm aware of (as of early 2017, at least). On models with front and back command dials, you can swap their functions — but not the direction in which they operate.